# How to achieve a HTML check in JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a check that will create the class `form-group has-success has-feedback` in a div and `glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback` in an `li`.

What I am trying to achieve (when user has filled it out correctly):

```
<div class="form-group has-success has-feedback ">
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

How my code looks like:

```
function InputChecker(InputChecker, tracker) {
    let div = ($('<div/>', {
        'class': InputChecker
    }));
    return div;
}

function password(tracker) {
    let input = ($('<input/>', {
        'type': 'password',
        'name': 'password',
        'class': 'form form-control',
        'id': 'password',
        'placeholder': 'Fill in your password (minimum length of 8 characters required!)',
        'required': true
    })).on('keyup', function() {
        tracker.pwd = $(this).val();

        if ($(this).val().length < 8) {
            var x = InputChecker('form-group has-success has-feedback', tracker);
            console.log(x);
            $(this).after('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></span>');    
        } else {
            // Do something else
        }
    });
    return input;
}
```

How my `document.ready` looks like:

```
let inputFieldStructure = $(eBlock('col-md-6 col-md-offset-3', tracker).append(InputChecker('', tracker)));
inputFieldStructure.append(loginName(tracker), userName(tracker), password(tracker), confirmPassword(tracker)).appendTo('#registerAndLogin');
```

How my HTML looks like:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h1>test</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <form action="registerAndLogin.php" method="POST" id="registerAndLogin">
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-footer">
                <h1>test</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Of course it is possible to call functions when an event happens - that is every-day practice used on countless web sites/apps. What is your specific problem in that regard? _“Right now it inserts it BEFORE even though (according to me) I have inserted it AFTER”_ - you have not even shown us the HTML this operates on, so how could we possibly tell? Please provide a proper [mcve].

Comment: Inserting a `li` directly after an `input` could not create a valid DOM structure to begin with though. `li` needs to be a child of a list.

Comment: @misorude giving you my HTML won't solve anything, considering I have pretty much nothing besides a form tag and the basic layout of HTML in it. everything is made with javascript, but let me throw in the HTML. Correct about the li directy after the input, but let me give you an example of what I am trying to make with js/jquery

Comment: Where do you want `<li>` in form? does `<li>` contain any data?

Comment: No, not yet, the li is meant as the span: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></span> . I made the edit so it's a bit clearer. it was sloppy from my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need two changes based upon information provided:

HTML:

```
<div id="passwordDiv">
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess">
    <span id="passwordSpan"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

JS on success:

```
if ($(this).val().length < 8) {
    $("#passwordDiv").addClass("form-group");
    $("#passwordDiv").addClass("has-success");
    $("#passwordDiv").addClass("has-feedback");
    $("#passwordSpan").addClass("glyphicon");
    $("#passwordSpan").addClass("glyphicon-ok");
    $("#passwordSpan").addClass("form-control-feedback");
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```